# For an embeddable widget font sizes is it possible to "mock" a root and stick with rem, or just use either px or em?

Tags: javascript, css, widget, font-size

Note: This is not a typical "em vs rem vs px" debate, as there's a rather important caveat.

I am making an embeddable widget that runs via a `script` tag and one root `div` being placed on the target page. I'm used to used `rem` for all of my sizes and using the 62.5% trick, but this is not a viable option for me because the `root` of my widget may have one size, but the `root` of the client's site could have another. This would mean all my elements with `rem` dimensions go wild.

Is there a way to indicate that **my** `root` is the one to follow? Or is there some other way of determining my own root font-size independent of the target site?

I've also considered using just `em`, and doing something like this:

```css
#my-root * {
  font-size: 62.5%
}
```

The idea being that I could then still use a decimal-based sizing system, although this would obviously become complicated as soon as I try to use a larger/smaller font size.

Is it best just to forego all of that and jsut use `px`? What are the best practices for third-party javascript widgets?